# Generate XML from Excel for recurring tags under each unique Element

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I need to generate XML file from Excel for recurring Attribute tags under each unique Data element. 
Below is the excel format. Uniqueness of the Data element is identified by the ID column which will not be displayed in the XML file.

**Excel Format: (Input)**

```
ID | Name | Description | AttributeName | AttributeValue
--------------------------------------------------------
01 | A    | Test1       | Width         | 33
   |      |             | Height        | 50
   |      |             | Length        | 25
02 | B    | Test2       | Width         | 55
   |      |             | Depth         | 88
```

**XML Format: (Expected Output)**

```
<Data name="A" description="Test1">
   <Attribute Name="Width" Value="33"/>
   <Attribute Name="Heigth" Value="50"/>
   <Attribute Name="Length" Value="25"/>
</Data>

<Data name="B" description="Test2">
   <Attribute Name="Width" Value="55"/>
   <Attribute Name="Depth" Value="88"/>
</Data>

</List>
```

This is what I have attempted to code.

**VBA Code:**

```
Sub GenerateXML_Test()
 Dim myFile As String

 'Create XML File
  myFile = ThisWorkbook.Path + "\TestXML.xml"
  Open myFile For Output As #1

 'Get Last Row
  LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row


  Print #1, "<List>" & vbNewLine

 'Print recurring text in xml file
  For RowIndex = 2 To LastRow

   Print #1, "<Data name=" & Chr(34) & Cells(RowIndex, 2).Value & Chr(34) & " Description=" & Chr(34) & Cells(RowIndex, 3).Value & Chr(34) & ">" & vbNewLine & "<Attribute Name=" & Chr(34) & Cells(RowIndex, 4).Value & Chr(34) & " Value=" & Chr(34) & Cells(RowIndex, 5).Value & Chr(34) & "/>" & "</Data>" & vbNewLine

  Next RowIndex

  Print #1, "</List>"

  Close #1

End Sub
```

**XML Format: (Actual Output)**

```
<List>
  <Data name="A" Description="Test1">
    <Attribute Name="Width" Value="33" /> 
  </Data>
  <Data name="" Description="">
    <Attribute Name="Height" Value="50" /> 
  </Data>
  <Data name="" Description="">
    <Attribute Name="Length" Value="25" /> 
  </Data>
  <Data name="B" Description="Test2">
    <Attribute Name="Width" Value="55" /> 
  </Data>
  <Data name="" Description="">
    <Attribute Name="Depth" Value="88" /> 
  </Data>
</List>
```

The output is not as Expected as I need to add the appropriate logic. The Attribute tags needs to be repeated in a single Data element for each unique ID. There can be any number of attributes for each of the data elements. 
Please help to add logic to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA comes equipped with a DOM builder using the [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object. Hence, you should not need to build a concatenated string in Excel of the XML document using a text stream.

Consider the following macro using the MSXML v6.0 reference interacting with node and attribute objects set up conditionally for empty column A values. Additionally, an XSLT (an [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)) is run on the raw output to pretty print the XML (without it XML content will show up on one long line):

```
Option Explicit

Sub xmlExport()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim doc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim root As IXMLDOMElement, dataNode As IXMLDOMElement, attribNode As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim dataNameAttrib As IXMLDOMAttribute, descAttrib As IXMLDOMAttribute
    Dim nameAttrib As IXMLDOMAttribute, valueAttrib As IXMLDOMAttribute
    Dim i As Long

    ' DECLARE XML DOC OBJECT '
    Set root = doc.createElement("List")
    doc.appendChild root

    ' WRITE TO XML '
    For i = 2 To Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count

        If Len(Trim(Range("A" & i))) <> 0 Then
            ' DATA NODE '
            Set dataNode = doc.createElement("Data")
            root.appendChild dataNode

            ' NAME ATTRIBUTE '
            Set dataNameAttrib = doc.createAttribute("name")
            dataNameAttrib.Value = Range("B" & i)
            dataNode.setAttributeNode dataNameAttrib

            ' DESCRIPTION ATTRIBUTE '
            Set descAttrib = doc.createAttribute("description")
            descAttrib.Value = Range("C" & i)
            dataNode.setAttributeNode descAttrib

            ' ATTRIBUTE NODE '
            Set attribNode = doc.createElement("Attribute")
            dataNode.appendChild attribNode
            ' NAME ATTRIBUTE '
            Set nameAttrib = doc.createAttribute("Name")
            nameAttrib.Value = Range("D" & i)
            attribNode.setAttributeNode nameAttrib
            ' VALUE ATTRIBUTE '
            Set valueAttrib = doc.createAttribute("Value")
            valueAttrib.Value = Range("E" & i)
            attribNode.setAttributeNode valueAttrib
        Else
            ' ATTRIBUTE NODE '
            Set attribNode = doc.createElement("Attribute")
            dataNode.appendChild attribNode
            ' NAME ATTRIBUTE '
            Set nameAttrib = doc.createAttribute("Name")
            nameAttrib.Value = Range("D" & i)
            attribNode.setAttributeNode nameAttrib
            ' VALUE ATTRIBUTE '
            Set valueAttrib = doc.createAttribute("Value")
            valueAttrib.Value = Range("E" & i)
            attribNode.setAttributeNode valueAttrib
        End If

    Next i

    ' PRETTY PRINT RAW OUTPUT '
    xslDoc.LoadXML "<?xml version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & "?>" _
            & "<xsl:stylesheet version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) _
            & "                xmlns:xsl=" & Chr(34) & "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" & Chr(34) & ">" _
            & "<xsl:strip-space elements=" & Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34) & " />" _
            & "<xsl:output method=" & Chr(34) & "xml" & Chr(34) & " indent=" & Chr(34) & "yes" & Chr(34) & "" _
            & "            encoding=" & Chr(34) & "UTF-8" & Chr(34) & "/>" _
            & " <xsl:template match=" & Chr(34) & "node() | @*" & Chr(34) & ">" _
            & "  <xsl:copy>" _
            & "   <xsl:apply-templates select=" & Chr(34) & "node() | @*" & Chr(34) & " />" _
            & "  </xsl:copy>" _
            & " </xsl:template>" _
            & "</xsl:stylesheet>"

    xslDoc.async = False
    doc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Output.xml"

    MsgBox "Successfully exported Excel data to XML!", vbInformation
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<List>
    <Data name="A" description="Test1">
        <Attribute Name="Width" Value="33"></Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="Height" Value="50"></Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="Length" Value="25"></Attribute>
    </Data>
    <Data name="B" description="Test2">
        <Attribute Name="Width" Value="55"></Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="Depth" Value="88"></Attribute>
    </Data>
</List>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nested loops. Something like this:

```vb
Sub GenerateXML_Test()
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim i As Integer
    'Create XML File
    myFile = ThisWorkbook.Path + "\TestXML.xml"
    Open myFile For Output As #1
    'Get Last Row
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Print #1, "<List>" & vbNewLine
    'Print recurring text in xml file
    For RowIndex = 2 To LastRow
        Print #1, "<Data name=""" & Cells(RowIndex, 2).Value & _
                  """ Description=""" & Cells(RowIndex, 3).Value & """>" & _
                  vbNewLine
        'Now loop through the attributes until we find another Data element
        Do While Cells(RowIndex, 2).Value <> ""
            Print #1, "<Attribute Name=""" & Cells(RowIndex, 4).Value & _
                      """ Value=""" & Cells(RowIndex, 5).Value & """/>" & _
                      vbNewLine
            'btw, incrementing a For variable manually like this is very bad form
            RowIndex = RowIndex + 1
            'I would restructure this once you grasp nesting loops.
        Loop
        Print #1, "</Data>" & vbNewLine
    Next RowIndex
    Print #1, "</List>"
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Also, use double quotes `""` instead of CHR(34).